# Codeigniter Ion Auth email activation is active already

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

Having the few more problems with Ion Auth.
I have set `$config['email_activation'] = TRUE`, and an email is sent. However, the "`activation_code`" in the MySQL table is now `NULL`, and `"active" = 1`. This is **before** the user activates.
I have made some changes to allow more fields, etc. and all was working fine. The actual activation code in the email seems fine (`http://domain.com/userID/code`), but while it used to be set in the DB, now it is not, or else, it is activated automatically (without the new user submitting the email link).

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to change `email_activation` to `true`

```
$config['email_activation'] = TRUE;
```

AND

```
$config['manual_activation'] = FALSE;
```

In your Ion Auth config.

Also, make sure `$this->ion_auth->errors()` isnt returning an error after you call `register()`.

Comment: All that checks out. Somehow it activates without running the activate function (controller). I'll have to track down where its happening.

Comment: It looks like the ion_auth_model activate() function is being called as soon as a user registers, but before they click the link.

Comment: @Ben how can I modify the value of "email_activation" within the controller? I've tried "$this->ion_auth->email_activation = true" but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem like that I got a email from with auth link and I never clicked auth link but the user already activated in the database.

so I modified activate.tpl.php like below without site_url() function and It worked..

I passed site_url to view file from controller $data..

---

```
<h1>Activate account for <?php echo $identity;?></h1>

<p><a href=<?=$site_url?>auth/activate/<?=$id;?>/<?=$activation;?>>Activate Your Account</a></p>
```